# In Gmail's unsubscribe popup (by list-unsubscribe header) - 'Go to website' button appears only at the second unsubscribe click

Tags: gmail, oneclick, list-unsubscribe

While trying to integrate emails with 'Unsubscribe' button:

```
// Headers:
{"List-Unsubscribe-Post", "List-Unsubscribe=One-Click"}
{"List-Unsubscribe", "<https://test.url.com/uns?u=AAA>"}
```

The Gmail unsubscribe button is appearing:

[image]

But when clicking the 'Unsubscribe' button in popup - it does not open the provided link (not in the background - checked by logs, and not in the browser).

Only when clicking it again - a new popup appears (different one) and the provided link is opened at the browser:

[image]

Other emails from other sites just show the 2nd popup at the first time,

what am I doing wrong here? thanks.

**UPDATE:**

After a few weeks, the second unsubscribe opportunity is not exists, there's no 'Unsubscribe' button after the first action.

Looks like Google has changed it. But still - its impossible to make the 'Unsubscribe' open the requested page.